# Name of a specific DRM technique

Tags: drm

Let's say I make a program. I only want this program to run on the computers on my internal network. If I move the program to a computer that is not on my network, then my program will not run. Basically, I want to be able to control which computers can run my program by having the client validate itself with a server. I would guess this would be a subset of DRM, but what is the name of what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_(software_licensing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_%28software_licensing%29)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am describing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you described is widely supported by systems such as the Orion software license management system. A single license server running on the company's global WAN/VPN/intranet manages the set number of licenses. Depending on how the licensing is configured, the application can automatically checkout a license on startup and return it on exit, or do a longer term checkout (or activation) which means that specific system has that license and will retain it through system or application shutdown/startup cycles. The application is also automatically locked to that system on checkout so it can't just be copied to another system. The license server ensures that not more than the licensed number of instances are active at any one time.

There are a number of issues you need to think about with such a system, such as:

- What if a user wants to obtain a license on a system lacking a
  network connection to the server?
- What happens if the user's system crashes: how can they release the
  license so it can used elsewhere?
- Can a user return the license so someone else can use it, and do
  you want to control how frequently this can occur?
- Do you want to control other limits on your product, such as a time limit, or configure product features?

Dominic